# Bring app to foreground from background, Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, foreground

I have an android app with a single activity which is launched with SingleInstance mode. The app has a countdown timer. When the app is minimized and goes to the background and other apps are used, I want to bring my app to front when the countdown timer finishes.

I tried:

`StartActivity(Intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront));`

But it does not bring my app to front. However, it may reactivate another app which is at the top of all minimized apps.

I have tried other `ActivityFlags` but they don't bring my app to front when it is minimized and another app is used. How can I bring the minimized app to front when other apps are used?

Comment: Not possible without user interaction, i.e. post a notification from your background service with the appropriate intents.

Comment: @SushiHangover But I know an app called "U-VPN" on google play that sometimes opens suddenly without user interaction!

Comment: @MinimusHeximus From [Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts), I agree with SushHangover, suggesting apps that are in the background should display time-sensitive notifications to provide urgent information to the user instead of directly starting an activity

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT If you try U-VPN in Google Play you can see that it pops up from background. So it is possible but I don't know how.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Sorry, I don't know U-VPN in Google Play, if you have best way to do this, please remember to share it, thanks.